# How do I get Google Cloud VPN connected to Cisco ASA

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Need to get the Google Cloud VPN connection established to third party's Cisco ASA.

Working with thirdparty service provider to setup a VPN to their network.

We are limited to IKEv1 by thirdparty.  I can see that connection is established, but then fail with no-proposal-chosen, which for me indicate that phase 2 encryption is not matching.  Forwarded all the links regarding the supported IKEv1 encryption algorithms along with Peer VPN setup guide.  For some reason they are wondering if Google Cloud VPN allow IPSec to a Cisco ASA.

These are the questions being asked by Third Party before they will continue with setup.  It would be great if somebody can assist to verify or correct my reponses below:

1. IS PFS enabled and what are specific phase2 as we are getting
   mismatch on phase
2. Do google VPN allow IPSec to a Cisco ASA
3. Do they allow static routing
4. Is the APN main mode

The responses that I am preparing.  Can somebody please correct or verify that my responses are correct:

1. Yes it is enabled, we are using a shared key.  Phase 2 mismatch is caused by encryption not matching and for PFS Algorithm must be set to "Group 2 (MODP_1024)". Ensure that IKE is set to "aes128-sha1-modp1024" and ESP value is "aes128-sha1".  Also ensure that NAT-T is off as Google Cloud does not support this.
2. Yes
3. Yes
4. Not sure on this question as I have only come across APN on modem configurations in the past usign SIM cards.

I have provided as much information to third party, based on Google's VPN documentation.

- [Google Cloud VPN Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/troubleshooting)
- [Google’s doc about Peer VPN setup](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns#setting_up_the_peer_vpn_gateway)

Error on Google Logs:

```
parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 reqeust ######## [ HASH N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
```

Third Party Cisco ASA error (**Phase 2 Mismatch**):

```
5   Nov 03 2016 11:49:34   713259   Group = xxx.xxx.x.xxx, IP = xxx.xxx.x.xxx, Session is being torn down. Reason: Phase 2 Mismatch
```

Details from Google Cloud VPN Troubleshooting guide:

> If the VPN logs indicate error no-proposal-chosen, this indicates that
>   there was no match between the algorithms configured on the pair of
>   VPN gateways. In IKEv1, the set of algorithms must be a complete
>   match.

How do I get the VPN connection established between the Google Cloud VPN and an Cisco ASA?

Comment: Also provided the advanced configuration guide: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced

Comment: The logs say that Google Cloud VPN received from ASA NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notification. Maybe more verbose logs in ASA can discover you which parameters aren't match?

Comment: Thanks, will go back to third party and see if they can do that.

Comment: // , Would you be willing to rephrase the title of this as a question, and summarize with one sentence at the bottom of the question?

Comment: I have updated the title and summarized with one sentence

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample configuration between different devices and Cloud VPN on this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/interop-guides). In the case of Cisco ASA only static routes are supported. The example provided uses a Cisco ASA 5005 appliance, IKEv2 and PFS on.  As mentioned in the comments of this thread, the supported ciphers for IKEv2 and IKEv1 can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced). When using IKEv1 the set of algorithms must be a [complete match](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks to all, updating this for reference for other individuals.  The issue was the encryption algorithms had to match and got provider to double check the following match:  IKE/ISAKMP aes128-sha1-modp1024
ESP aes128-sha1
PFS Algorithm Group 2 (MODP_1024)
NAT-T off (Cloud VPN does not support NAT-T)